# ChildNodes seemingly not existing in DOM while using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, timing, mutation-observers

I am trying to use MutationObserver to observe changes in the DOM but it seems like I can't access the "grand"-children nodes. I have configured the observer with subtree and childList values. As I understand, it is not possible to get the entire DOM-tree of added childLists or changes with the MutationObserver, all it does is observe the changes. Instead you are supposed to use getElementById.

I've tried using getElementById to find the relevant "parent"-node in the DOM after the change is observed, and then crawl all the childNodes. Although I still get no hits on the childNodes.

I assume the "parent"-node is inserted onto the DOM first, and the childNodes are then inserted on to the "parent"-node after the fact, though these events are not triggered in the  observer for some reason.

I suspect I might need to update the target of the MutationObserver as I observe the changes, and then continuously use getElementById and crawl these nodes.

Any idea on why these childNodes are not observable, and/or how to approach the solution to this?

Best regards.

Code to MutationObserver

```
function createObserver() {
    const documentBody = document.body;

    // callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
        let addedNodes = []

        for (const mut of mutationRecords) {

            let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(mut.addedNodes)
            arr = arr.filter(node => popupTagNames.includes(node.tagName)); // Keep only selected tags

            if (arr.length == 0) return; // don't keep empty

            addedNodes = addedNodes.concat(arr)

            let el = document.getElementById(addedNodes[0].id);

            // Crawler
            inspectNode(el)
        }


    })

    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true }
    observer.observe(documentBody, config)
}
```

Comment: addedNodes isn't flattened. A big sub-tree may be added in one mutation as one node. You need to check the children of each added node e.g. using querySelector.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you kindly for your response. I have tried using querySelector before this with no luck. Unfortunately no sub-trees are found, if only that was the case then I would be able to crawl it.

Comment: It would be a bug in the browser, which is unlikely. Can you show an [MCVE](/help/mcve) or a link to the site?

Comment: Yes, I have been testing on this danish site: https://nyheder.tv2.dk/politik
I can add the code to the crawler as well, although it is rather large.

Comment: So which node there is the parent?

Comment: I want to observe the div with id **#qc-cmp2-container** being added. I can see it added with a direct child, but no further children ("grand"-children"). PS. It is the cookie message, in case the message is accepted and cookies should be cleared

Comment: The inner elements are added without an id so your `el` will be null. It might be best to attach a second observer on the parent, otherwise you'll need to verify which addedNode is inside the parent by using parent.contains(node), for example.

Comment: The `el` is the parent and should contain the inner elements, so I can crawl them, although this is not the case...

Comment: `addedNodes[0].id` will be undefined for the subsequently added children inside that parent.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure I follow. `addedNodes[0].id` will only contain one element which would be the parent element. Any added children are not observed, infact if that was the case I would have no issues. The `el` element should then be crawleable as I can see it contains childNodes in the DOM, although it is not crawleable. I use the function `inspectNode(el)` to crawl the parent element. I will add the crawler code to the main post.

Comment: No, you observe the entire body recursively so the subsequently added children will be reported in a separate call and they don't have an id. I've verified it myself.

Comment: How would I go about observing the subsequently added children?

Comment: I've already described it in my comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's investigate by logging the added nodes that belong to #qc-cmp2-container element:

```js
new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  const parent = document.getElementById('qc-cmp2-container');
  if (parent) console.log(...mutations.flatMap(m =>
    [...m.addedNodes].filter(n => parent.contains(n)).map(n => n.cloneNode(true))));
}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

We'll see several separate calls:

1. The main #qc-cmp2-container and its empty child
2. An inner div with a lot of child elements and text
3. Two additional inner elements are added

The most resource-effective solution is to wait for the parent using the super fast getElementById check and then switch to observing the parent:

```js
function waitForId(id, callback) {
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) {
    callback(el);
  } else {
    new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
      el = document.getElementById(id);
      if (el) {
        observer.disconnect();
        callback(el);
      }
    }).observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
  }
}

waitForId('qc-cmp2-container', parent => {
  new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
    // do something
  }).observe(parent, { subtree: true, childList: true });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I made it work with a setTimeout(..., 0). As I am observing multiple sites, I am not certain of the ID to wait for...